# Add Github Identity Provider to AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, github-api

I have created a Github OAuth app and I am trying to add the app as an OIDC application to AWS Cognito.

However, I cannot find a proper overview about the endpoints and data to fill in anywhere in the Github Docs.

The following fields are required:

**Issuer** -> ?

**Authorization endpoint** => https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize (?)

**Token endpoint** => https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token (?)

**Userinfo endpoint** =>  https://api.github.com/user  (?)

**Jwks uri** => ?

I couldn't find the Jwks uri anywhere. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to get this working out of the box.

https://github.com/TimothyJones/github-cognito-openid-wrapper seems to be a way to get this working.

If any Cognito dev sees this, please add Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket support.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 14.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/01/22/gitlab-14-7-released/#openid-connect-support-for-gitlab-cicd) (January 2022) might help:

> ### OpenID Connect support for GitLab CI/CD
>
> Connecting GitLab CI/CD to cloud providers using environment variables works fine for many use cases.
> However, it doesn’t scale well if you need advanced permissions management or would prefer a signed, short-lived, contextualized connection to your cloud provider.
>
> GitLab 12.10 shipped initial support for JWT token-based connection (`CI_JOB_JWT`) to enable HashiCorp Vault users to safely retrieve secrets. That implementation was restricted to Vault, while the logic we built JWT upon opened up the possibility to connect to other providers as well.
>
> In GitLab 14.7, we are introducing a [`CI_JOB_JWT_V2`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/) environment variable that can be used to connect to AWS, GCP, Vault, and likely many other cloud services.
> Please note that this is an [alpha](/handbook/product/gitlab-the-product/#alpha) feature and not ready for production use. Your feedback is welcomed in [this epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7335).
>
> For AWS specifically, with the new `CI_JOB_JWT_V2` variable, you can connect to AWS to retrieve secrets, or to deploy within your account. You can also manage access rights to your cluster using AWS IAM roles.
> You can read more on setting up [OIDC connection with AWS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/aws/).
>
> The new variable is automatically injected into your pipeline but is not backward compatible with the current `CI_JOB_JWT`.
> Until GitLab 15.0, the `CI_JOB_JWT` will continue to work normally but this will change in a [future release](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/349110). We will notify you about the change in time.
> The `secrets` stanza today uses the `CI_JOB_JWT_V1` variable. If you use the `secrets` stanza, you don’t have to make any changes yet.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_7/oidc.drawio.png -- OpenID Connect support for GitLab CI/CD]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29047).